# RabbitMQ with Hessian web service protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, hessian

In my iphone application to `get request/response from server using RabbitMQ` and my server side using java application.

In this case i need to integrate **hessian protocol** inside my iphone app,

> what we have to send serialise and de-serialise the object to byte
>   array.

It is possible to use hessian protocol inside the iOS application? If it is possible to give correct solution with sample project.